# Google drive API combining image and text

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file and an image using the google drive api example for iOS.

It's easy to upload text and image separately but I can't figure out how to upload both.
How do you combine an image and text?
If I do this:

```
  NSData *fileContent = [self.textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.someImage.image);
  NSMutableData *uploadData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:fileContent];
  [uploadData appendData:imageData];

  uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:uploadData MIMEType:@"multipart/related"];
```

It will upload both but I can't view it on my drive.

Do I have to create a google doc?
If so, what is the format of a google doc? 
I create a doc on my drive and added some text and image to it so that works, so google docs can definitely handle text and images in the same file.

I searched for Google doc format but nothing comes up there either (if this is the right approach).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure how you are uploading them together? What kind of file are you expecting to have in your Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to upload a formatted document that contains both text & images, that is considered a single file and must be uploaded that way. There isn't a way to directly upload in the native Google Docs format, but you can use one of the other supported formats like DOCX, PDF, etc and convert them.